# Deshabilitar una fecha que ya esta registrado con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

> Estoy realizando un sistema donde los pacientes pueden solicitar citas en linea.
> Como puedo hacer para que las fechas que ya tienen cita(fechacita) se bloqueen y no puedan ser eligidas por otro paciente o el mismo paciente con PHP

```
CREATE TABLE cita(
idcita int auto_increment,
fechacita date not null,
horacita time not null,
descrip text not null,
especialidad varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_cita primary key (idcita)
);
```

Comment: Crear una funcion que bloque los dias que ya estan registrado en fechacita

Comment: Lo que quiero es como crear esa funcion yo no cuento con esa funcion

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes para realizar el guardado de citas.

Comment: Te hará falta una nueva tabla llamada más o menos `citas_registradas` donde almacenarás las citas que ya hayan sido reservadas. Así, en la página que usas para que se escojan las citas muestras únicamente aquellas disponibles (confrotando tu tabla `citas` con tu tabla `citas_registradas`). Aparte de eso tendrás que poner en el cliente una consulta con un temporizador para ir actualizando las citas disponibles desde el servidor (pienso en conexiones concurrentes, o sea, varios usuarios al mismo tiempo eligiendo citas).